# Using SmartGit's SSH client in hooks

Tags: git, ssh, smartgit

When using a git repository hook, how can I use SmartGit's internal SSH client?

When using a hook with a `scp` operation, I receive a `Permission Denied: (publickey)` error.

SmartGit is aware of the credentials, they are listed under `Edit > Preferences > Commands > Authentication`, when pulling from the repository.

I require a commit-msg hook to generate Change-Id: tags in commit messages which is required for proper gerrit functioning (setup using the [Mahara developer contribution guide](https://wiki.mahara.org/index.php/Developer_Area/Contributing_Code)):

```
#!/bin/sh
scp -p -P 29418 username@reviews.mahara.org:hooks/commit-msg .git/hooks/
```

Comment: Why do you need access to the SSH client in your hook? What kind of hook is it?

Comment: @mstrap updated the OP with clarification on the setup, and reasoning for the scp.

Comment: I'm using Gerrit the too (for the jgit project), but I just needed to *download* the commit-msg once using scp. The hook itself requires no online connection to the repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. When SmartGit invokes the Git binaries, it sets `GIT_SSH` environment variable to its internal client only for certain commands, like `push` and `pull`, but not for `commit`. So you will have to configure your SSH client manually, if you really think you will need a connection to the remote repository on commit (what IMHO shouldn't be necessary).

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a ````GIT_SSH```` environment variable (added ````set```` to the hook to view them)

Comment: Sorry, actually not set for commit. Please see my updated answer.